# Calling hystrix command in fallback method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am planning to use the hystrix command to publish a message to rabbitmq. If the publish fails for whatever reason, i want to fallback on a webservice call. Now i also want this webservice call to be protected by hystrix. If this call also fails, i want to log the exception and abort. I am using spring boot with hystrix annotations. My understanding is that hystrix command cannot be applied on fallback method. Instead we have to create a new spring component class with a method annotated with hystrixcommand and inject it and use it in the fallback method. Is this the only way or is there a simpler way to do this without creating a new class?

Comment: What you describe is a valid pattern. Have you tried it and it failed?

Comment: You are right. It works. I misunderstood. Thank you.